# How to get my program to run outside of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, export, processing

I have a project in eclipse.  It does everything I want it to do when I click on the green circle play button in the IDE - opens the window, plays the stuff, everything.  But, try as I might, I cannot figure out how to get it to do that outside of eclipse.

My project uses the processing.core library to do some of its stuff, but I am unable to get the project to function in the Processing IDE, because of some stupid stuff about one of my classes not being a valid substitute for the type parameter for `Collections.sort(List<T>)`.  If anyone knows how I can get it to export from the Processing IDE, that would be excellent.

I need to be able to email/upload to the internet/otherwise transmit some kind of file/folder/webpage that allows the recipient to, without much technical knowledge or work on their part, view a window or something that allows them to view and interact with the program in the same way I am able to interact with the window that Eclipse launches when I press the play button at the top.

I have tried several different ways of accomplishing this, but none of them have worked.  I tried exporting a runnable `.jar`, but it wouldn't let me include the referenced libraries.  I tried a regular `.jar`, but I don't know how to package that up with whatever is needed to  be able to view it.  I've even tried using the fat jar eclipse plugin for it, too, but I ran afoul of something about being unable to find the main `PApplet` class for the project.

If anybody knows how to get what I want to happen, or knows of a good tutorial on how to do what I want, I would greatly appreciate any sort of assistance or guidance or anything.

Google has been unhelpful in turning up solutions to this problem, because most of the results I have found were just other people asking the same or a similar question, and then either no answer, or something I had already tried, with no indication of exactly what sort of options or settings I needed to give it in order to accomplish the task.

I am using the `processing.core.jar` from version 2.0b7, but I don't think that would make a difference, although I plan to try it with different versions if I can't figure out anything else.

A copy of my project folder can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1n4curhxbgi8fye/A5F6_l7xQu

All the data I have is stuff I've concatenated together from successive versions of the file at http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/eqs7day-M1.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done a quick test on OSX and had to tweak your eclipse project a bit:

1. You are linking to .jar libraries using absolute path. I recommend using keeping libraries relative to the project
2. I ran into some memory issues and had to add a couple of compiler flags
3. Added a main method in Earthquaker.java to initialize as an application.

main looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main(Earthquaker.class.getSimpleName());
    }
```

In eclipse you can export a runnable jar via **File > Export > Java > Runnable JAR file**. Here are a couple of screenshots:

[image: eclipse jar export 1]

[image: eclipse jar export 2]

Personally I prefer using the **"Copy required libraries into a sub-folder..."** option in case I need to update some dependent .jar independent of the main application .jar.

For reference I've uploaded the modified eclipse project [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/Processing-DataVisualization.zip)(Java SDK will need to be changed). The exported runnable jar with a bash script is available [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/EarthQuake.zip).

And here is the bash script itself which should run on Linux as well:

```
java -Xms128M -Xmx1024M -jar Processing-DataVisualization.jar
```

Pretty cool project btw.

Comment: no worries,glad it worked. pretty neat project as I mentioned. As a side note, I had to do something like this recently on windows but also using native libraries(jogl,opencv,etc.). In case you need to do that in the future, place the native libraries in a folder(e.g. `./nativeLibs`) then just add this VM argument: `-Djava.library.path=./nativeLibs`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a simple jar. Create a batch file and specify the class path. Save the batch file. Runnin the batch file will run the app

```
@ECHO OFF
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;myjar1.jar;myjar2.jar;

java mypackage.MyClass
```

Comment: How would you do that using a linux shell script?  I'm on linux, so batch doesn't work.

Comment: which shell?  most likely the only changes you need are remove "@echo off" and change the classpath seperator to :

Comment: put all your jars in a lib directory.
$ java -cp lib/*.jar mypackage.MyClass